# C++ boost build errors

Tags: c++

we use boost1.46.1 in our c++ project. When I am building my c++ project using cmake, I am getting following errors.

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Can any one please hemp me to  fix the following errors?

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicuuc.so.44, needed by /efs/dist/fsf/boost/1.46.1-build001/.exec/x86-32.rhel.5/rh346/lib/libboost_regex.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicui18n.so.44, needed by /efs/dist/fsf/boost/1.46.1-build001/.exec/x86-32.rhel.5/rh346/lib/libboost_regex.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicudata.so.44, needed by /efs/dist/fsf/boost/1.46.1-build001/.exec/x86-32.rhel.5/rh346/lib/libboost_regex.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/efs/dist/fsf/boost/1.46.1-build001/.exec/x86-32.rhel.5/rh346/lib/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `u_isspace_44'
/efs/dist/fsf/boost/1.46.1-build001/.exec/x86-32.rhel.5/rh346/lib/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `icu_44::Collator::createInstance(icu_44::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)'
/efs/dist/fsf/boost/1.46.1-build001/.exec/x86-32.rhel.5/rh346/lib/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `u_charFromName_44'
/efs/dist/fsf/boost/1.46.1-build001/.exec/x86-32.rhel.5/rh346/lib/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `u_charType_44'
/efs/dist/fsf/boost/1.46.1-build001/.exec/x86-32.rhel.5/rh346/lib/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `u_digit_44'
/efs/dist/fsf/boost/1.46.1-build001/.exec/x86-32.rhel.5/rh346/lib/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `u_tolower_44'
/efs/dist/fsf/boost/1.46.1-build001/.exec/x86-32.rhel.5/rh346/lib/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `icu_44::Locale::~Locale()'
/efs/dist/fsf/boost/1.46.1-build001/.exec/x86-32.rhel.5/rh346/lib/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `u_isblank_44'
/efs/dist/fsf/boost/1.46.1-build001/.exec/x86-32.rhel.5/rh346/lib/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `icu_44::Locale::Locale()'
/efs/dist/fsf/boost/1.46.1-build001/.exec/x86-32.rhel.5/rh346/lib/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `icu_44::Locale::Locale(icu_44::Locale const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The boost::regex library is not header only, are you sure the shared libraries have been built and are visible to the linker?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html

It looks like boost::regex sometimes depends on the ICU library.  You can either link against that library, or you can follow the instructions in the link to disable ICU.

Answer (score 1):

Your Boost.Regex is built with Unicode support — you need to link to [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) as well.

Comment: A few question about your answer:
how do you know that?
how can I test it to be sure?
how do I link to ICU?